# JSP display first then do business logic

Tags: java

My requirement is to display userName and FirstName first then try logic next....but here after some time in try block(few secs for try logic loading/execution) then userName and password displaying in page...How can i display userName/Firstanme then try logic next.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>

  <% 
  String lastname= request.getParameter("lastname");  
  String firstname= request.getParameter("firstname");
  %>

 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>Firstname</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td><%=firstname %></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Lastname</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td><%=lastname %></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody> 

  <% 
   try
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Thread");
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
    }
    catch(Exception ex1)
    {
        System.out.println(ex1.getMessage());
    }
   %>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: Why are you using scriplets in JSP, they are not recommended, aren't you aware of it?

Comment: Please explain what is your exact need, as per your code, what you describe is correct only. What are you trying to achieve using sleep() method here?

Comment: ABU :  I know java code(business logic) should be written separately in java class.. but in my project everything should be within JSP.

Comment: Jayesh :    In sleep method some business logic is running internally which may take some time to execute..I want to print username and lastname first which is not dependent on this sleep method then sleep related stuff display...inputs to solve appreciated

Answer (score 0):

JSP is serverside language, the whole page is rendered, then send back to browser/client.
So with JSP you cannot do this.

You can include javascript in your jsp page, which talks to a webservice that does the logic you want it to do. The webservice can also return data that you can use to update your page...

I suggest you lookup AJAx on the web, a good place to start is:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Hi i need to fix this its urgent for me, Please some one send code for this requirement...Thx.....